# Android 3.2 videos on webapp with phonegap

Tags: android, html, video, webview, playback

I already know the issue about videos not playing on webview. I found the `video.js` plugin from Simon Mac Donald.

I did all the process of installation, but now i don´t know where tu put the code.

```
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://path.to.my/file.mp4");
```

In my page there is a button linked to a `video.html` where the video will be launched on full screen, play, stop and give a option to replay or to come back to the button´s page. For instance:

```
<li id="XY"><a href="video.html" target="_self" id="menubt"><span>goods</span></a></li>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This code is written in javascript inside the script tag like below:

```
$("#video").live('click', function(){

    alert('video sample');

    window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///sdcard/famous.3gp");       

});
```

where #video is the id of the html element.

But in this also i am facing error alert which says "sorry, this video can not be played"

Not sure why.